# Convert raw depth data from depth image to meters (Kinect v2)

Tags: ros, kinect, depth-image, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using Kinect v2 and I am trying to convert its raw values from the depth image to meters. I am subscribing to the `image_depth_rect` topic. **Firstly, I would like to ask if I need to calibrate the depth image with the color image I get from the sensor ?**

I have searched for similar issues, but all I found is info about the sensor from the previous version. I also found some stuff outside from ROS which didn't help.

**Is there an equation to convert the unsigned 16bit data that I get in meters?**

Currently I am using the following callback function for the depth image topic:

```
void kinectdepthCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg2){
    
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr2;
    try{
        cv_ptr2 = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg2, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_16UC1); 
    }
    catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e){
        ROS_ERROR("Could not convert from '%s' to '16UC1'.", e.what());
    return;
    }
    cv::imshow("Depth Image",cv_ptr2->image);
    cv::waitKey(20);
    ROS_INFO("The object is in depth: %d",cv_ptr2->image.at<int>(x,y));
    
    
}
```

where (x,y) are some points of the detected object but I get wrong results.

To be more specific, I detect an orange marker but I cannot get its depth from the Kinect v2. I present the following images:

Color image with detected object:

[image: image description]

Thresholded image:

[image: image description]

Depth image is black:

[image: image description]

Terminal messages from the above code:

[image: image description]

I don't know what is wrong and I get zero depth even if the object is at approximately a 19 - 20 cm. I have tried to find the depth in bigger depths like 60 cm, but I was still getting 0 results.

Thanks for answering in advance,

Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245652/convert-raw-depth-data-from-depth-image-to-meters-(kinect-v2)/) by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-10-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2016-10-14**:
does this help: http://answers.ros.org/question/160611/how-can-i-get-depth-data-from-kinect/
?

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-10-14**:
In the example he just gets the raw data from kinect. I am using a kinect v2 and I am trying to make this data into meters. Unless Kinect v2 and its [tools](https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2) do this automatically, which is something I don't know...

**Comment by [Abdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30451/abdu/) on 2017-07-17**:
Hi,
I have simple python code for detecting and tracking the object based on color by using webcam.
My question is how can I use the same code but by using Kinect v2 (NOT webcam).

can u plz help with this, and tell me how to use Kinect v2 as webcam in linux? or share your method ?

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2017-07-17**:
You want to use Kinect v2 in linux or in ROS? This topic has to do with integrating Kinect v2 into ROS as a node and manipulating its data with `cv_bridge`. Take a look [here](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages) for that.

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2017-07-17**:
If you want to use Kinect v2 in linux, you need to install the drivers from [here](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2) and ask in another more relative forum for that. A simple googling of your issue will also help you with your problem also.

Good luck!

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2017-07-17**:
For integrating Kinect v2 into ROS, also check [this](http://www.ros.org/news/2014/09/microsoft-kinect-v2-driver-released.html).

**Comment by [Abdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30451/abdu/) on 2017-07-17**:
Thanks for you guys, I know how to use kinect v2 with ROS, but I don't know how to use it as a webcam, because my code is in python and using webcam, but I want to modify it so it would use kinect v2 not webcam. That's why I ask Chris to pass the code, cuz its for color detection by using kinect v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Better calibration of the sensor and `<ushort>` casting will do the work. The raw data from the Kinect v2 are in millimeters.

---

Originally posted by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) with karma: 354 on 2016-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0